# Problema con Leyenda de ggplot2 en R

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2, graph, ggplot

tengo un inconveniente con la creación de una gráfica, mi código es el siguiente:

```
ggplot(data = db, aes(x = db$period, y = db$FBCF, group = 1))+
  geom_point(color = quarter, size = quarter)+
  geom_line(aes(x = db$period, y = db$FBCF, group = 1))+
  labs(x = "Periodo",
    y = "FBCF",
    title = "Serie de Tiempo FBCF",
    subtitle = "1996 - 2022")+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    legend.position = c(.02, .98),
    legend.justification = c("left", "top"))
```

a la hora de correr el código, este me salta de la siguiente forma:

[image: Grafica a partir del codigo]

Viendo esto, no entiendo el por que de que no me salte la leyenda del mismo, dado que condiciono el color y el tamaño de los scatterplot dado una variable que tiene 4 valores. También compartiré parte de la muestra de mi código para su mayor comprensión:

[image: Muestra de la base de datos]

Espero puedan ayudarme a lograr visualizar la leyenda de los trimestres. Gracias!

Comment: Me parece que necesitas publicar los datos. Se me ocurre que los puedes poner en GitHub o GitLab y publicar un link. Tu código debe ser reproducible. O si están en el internet, puedes poner el link. La foto de tus datos no es suficiente.

Comment: Por empezar tienes algunos problemas en tu código, la definición del `geom_point()` está mal, debería ser así `geom_point(aes(color = quarter, size = quarter))` por otro lado, evita hacer esto `aes(x = db$period, y = db$FBCF)` mejor `aes(x = period, y = FBCF)`. Arreglando estas cosas, y probando con datos sintéticos, aún no logro reproducir el problema. Revisa el ejemplo que has dado y agrega cualquier mensaje de warning o error, también deberías agregar un ejemplo mínimo de los datos, por ejemplo, pegando la salida de `dput(head(db))`